Noise Figure at the Rx ADC output
I need to measure gain & nf of the Rx at the ADC output. I inject sine wave tone to the Rx input. Then I make a ram dump of the IF ADC output, read it, perform fft and finally get the IF PSD.
My question is how to measure nf in a right way for that case?
Does it correct to use so called "gain method? NF=NPdevice–(−174+10log(BW)+Gain). If so, how to determine RBW for this kind of spectrum?


To calculate NF you need to know the input SNR

Yes, sure. I measured input tone from gen with spec analyzer and certain RBW.
